# Write a regex which contain a fix string and only some part will vary

Tags: regex

I need some help writing a regex that contains string with the varying word in the end.

Something like this

```
  \'This is a [a-z]'\
```

it  means  it should contain  all the strings like

```
This is a apple 
this is a x...
 .....
```

I know this is a simple question, and there must be some answer on SO, but I am unable to find one so Can someone please help me to write this kind of regex

Comment: Any part of the regexp that doesn't contain special operators is just matched exactly.

Comment: There's a regular expression tutorial at www.regular-expression.info.

Comment: so is my regex  correct ? @Barmar

Comment: `[Tt]his is a [a-zA-Z]*`

Comment: You probably need a quantifier after `[a-z]` so it will match the whole word, `[a-z]+`.

Comment: you can use `[Tt]his is a [a-z\s]*`

Comment: @Barmar Updated my above comment.  I'm not going to answer this.

Comment: Ok thanks TIM,BARMER , PAVNEET,   i get it

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen My comment wasn't meant for you, it was to the OP.

Comment: Thannnnnnnnnnnnks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following regular expression to match these strings:

```
/^[Tt]his is a ([A-Za-z]+)$/;
```

- `^`: Beginning of the string
- `[Tt]`: Either `T` or `t`
- `[A-Za-z]`: A set of all characters between A and Z, no matter what case
- `+`: At least one occurence of the preceding set
- `$`: End of the string, it therefore won't match `This is a pineapple3`

**Here is an example of the matching in JavaScript:**

```js
var text = "This is a pineapple";
var regex = /^[Tt]his is a ([A-Za-z]+)$/;

var matches = text.match(regex);
if(matches) {
  console.log("It matches. The word is:", matches[1]);
}
else {
  console.log("It does not match.");
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old thread, but I'd like to add comment here to thank the respondent @ssc-hrep3 for such a great answer - specifically - deconstructing the RegEx and explaining what each part does. This is great. Thank you.